# How do i properly use conduit across roof shingles?

Tags: electrical, grounding, tv-antenna, shingles

I am grounding an antenna and I have two 10 gauge copper wires from the antenna and coax ground block to the ground rod and I am going to put the wires in some 3/8" flexible conduit. Is there a proper way to do this across shingles? I can't find anything online.  The way my roof is set up the highest peak is in the middle of the roof away from the side of the house so there is about 8 feet of wire running across the shingles on a side roof area. Do I need to have this raised off the roof or can I just lay it on there?

Here is a picture of how I have it temporarily, the edge of the photo is where the roof ends and it goes down to the ground rod.
[image: how do i properly lay these wires]

Answer (score 2):

If there's a solar equipment distributor near you, check with them. Products like this

[image: roof flashing]

exist for this very purpose.

Ironically, because you're just grounding the equipment, the conduit itself, if it's metal, can serve as the grounding conductor (so it'd be empty conduit).

Look for "conduit roof flashing."